# infinite cyclic group is isomorphic to the group of integers under addition.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> Theorem:
>
> Every infinite cyclic group is Isomorphic to $\left ( \mathbb{Z},+ \right )$

Proof:

We show first that the map $\phi$ is a homomorphism.
Then, show that $\phi$ is a bijection.
Showing  $\phi$ is a homomorphism here is trivial so I'll leave that out.

Let $G=\left \langle g \right \rangle$ be an infinite cyclic group.
As a note, recall that $\left | g \right |=\left | \left \langle g \right \rangle \right |$

Define

$\phi:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow G$

$\space$ $n \mapsto g^{n}$

$\phi\left ( n \right ) =g^{n}$

Since $G=\left \{ g^{n}\mid n \in \mathbb{Z} \right \}$, 
Then, $\space$ $\forall x \in G$
$x=g^{n}$ $\space\ \exists n \in \mathbb{Z}$
Evidently, this means that every element in G is the image of at least one element n in $\mathbb{Z}$. This is equivalent to the definition of onto.

Moving on to showing one-to-one,

a function $\phi$ is one-to-one IFF $\phi\left ( n \right )=\phi\left ( m \right )$ implies n=m
$\forall n,m \in \mathbb{Z}$

Here's my reasoning and I'll like to know if it is valid.

The group G is an infinite cyclic group. So its order is infinite. 
This is equivalent to stating that there is an element g in G with infinite order. Then, all power of the element g in G is distinct group elements. 
If $\phi\left ( m \right )=\phi\left ( n \right )$ then $\space$ $g^{m}=g^{n}$
But the elements in G are distinct so the only solution is for $m=n$.

Hence, $\phi$ is one-to-one.

So, we have an Isomorphism $\phi$.

Comment: Please look through this one more time yourself. There are some obvious typos as well as a very weird start where you mention the map $\phi$ before even defining it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution has some strange typos in it, but to answer the actual question ("is the argument for one-to-one valid?"): yes it is, but could be made a bit clearer.

As you note, we want to show that $\phi(m) = \phi(n)$ implies $m = n$. But if $\phi(m) = \phi(n)$ then $g^m = g^n$, so $g^{m-n} = 1$. Since $g$ has infinite order, the only value of $m-n$ for which this is true is $m-n = 0$, *i.e.* $m = n$.

Answer (score -1):

What if we want to show that a map $φ:G\to(\mathbb{Z},+)$ as $φ(x)=x$ for every $x\in G$ is isomorphism ?

You can show that $φ$ is homomorphism and also $Ker(φ)=\{1_G\}$, $Im(φ)=\mathbb{Z}$. So $φ$ is also isomorphism.

Is this a wrong argument in regard to the choice of the map ?

Comment: seems too brief

Comment: Which means what?

Comment: i am saying that your answer didnt specifically explain some parts

Comment: Oh sorry you are right. I don’t have time right now. I will post specifics later. Thank you for your  answer.

Comment: Is this a new question? If so, it shouldn't be posted as an answer to an existing question.

Comment: No it's not. I propose a different proof to the theorem above, but I am not sure if it's correct.

Comment: If $G \neq \Bbb Z$, then $\phi(x) = x$ is a function from $G \to G$, not $G \to \Bbb Z$. It’s the identity map from $G$ to itself.